# Pointer (address) with if statement

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, pointer-address

I had a working code that gave me the address of a mesh (if i'm correct):

```
MyMesh &mesh = glWidget->mesh();
```

Now I want if thingie to assign different mesh adresses. One is mesh() first function and another function mesh(int): How is this done?

```
 MyMesh &mesh;  //error here: need to be initialized

 if(meshNum==0){
mesh = glWidget->mesh();
 }
 else if (meshNum==1){
mesh = glWidget->mesh(0);
 }
 else{
  return;
 }

 //mesh used in functions...
 function(mesh,...);
```

Comment: It's a reference, not a pointer.

Comment: what is the signature of the mesh() function you're calling on glWidget? Does it return a MyMesh, a MyMesh& or a MyMesh*?

Comment: `if (meshNum > 1 || meshNum < 0) return; MyMesh& mesh(meshNum == 0 ? glWidget->mesh() : glWidget->mesh(0));`

Comment: Thanks everybody! Problem solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your case is simple enough that `meshNum` is constrained, you can use the `?:` operator:

```
MyMesh &mesh = (meshNum == 0) ? glWidget->mesh() : glWidget->mesh(0);
```

Otherwise, you need a pointer since references **must** be initializated at the definition point, and cannot be reseated to refer to anything else.

```
MyMesh *mesh = 0;
if( meshNum == 0 ) {
    mesh = &glWidget->mesh();
} else if ( meshNum == 1 ){
    mesh = &glWidget->mesh(0);
}

function( *mesh, ... );
```

Comment: Always a fan of ternary conditions! But, you forgot to close that condition.

Answer (score 2):

References *must* be bound to an object at initialization ... you cannot have a default-initialized or zero-initialized reference.  So code like:

```
MyMesh &mesh;
```

where `mesh` is a non-constant l-value reference to a `Mesh` object, is inherently ill-formed.  At the point of declaration, you must bind the non-constant reference to a valid memory-addressable object.

Answer (score 0):

References are valid at all times in a well behaved program, so no, you cannot do that.  However, why not just:

```
if(meshNum != 0 && meshNum != 1)
    return;
function((meshNum == 0) ? glWidget->mesh() : glWidget->mesh(0));
```

Or you could just use a pointer and deference it later:

```
MyMesh *mesh = 0;
if(meshNum==0) {
    mesh = &glWidget->mesh();
}
else if (meshNum==1) {
    mesh = &glWidget->mesh(0);
}
else {
  return;
}

function(*mesh);
```